# Traversing through DOM to find a node and runtime considerations

Tags: javascript

Given a target node and root node, the below code traverses through the DOM to find the target recursively. Can someone walk me through what the loop is doing in regards to the `el` variable? also why `!el` is necessary in the loop condition?

Lastly, what is the runtime of the below function and how can we determine it without knowing what the DOM looks like?

```
function traverse(target, current) {
    if(current.isEqualNode(target))    
        return current;
    
    let el = null;
    for(let i=0; !el && i < current.children.length; i++) {
        el = traverse(target, current.children[i]);
    }
    
    return el;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop is looping through the children (every `DOM element` can have more than one child), and the `!el` is required because as you can see in the base case

```
if(current.isEqualNode(target))    
    return current;
```

you will return the node if you find it, otherwise `null`, and so the `!el` in the loop guard is there to say "loop until el is null (if is not, i've found the node that i'm interested in, so stop) and until this node a children to check"

Comment: Thank you for explaining that. I am still not 100% clear on how `null` relates to the base case. Also, how would we determine the runtime complexity of this function?

Comment: @AnchovyLegend well, the function in pre and post  condition should be `given a DOM node to search, and another one to find, return the node if it's found, null otherwise`, and in the loop `e`l is always null except if the recursive call return something not null, and so return the node that you was looking for

Comment: @AnchovyLegend about the complexity, is a complete tree traversal, so if you have N nodes, the worst case is that you won't find it, and so you need to travers the whole tree to find out that no node are the one you was looking for, so there is N recursive calls, and since you are doing constant work in every call, you have a complexity O(N) where N is the number of nodes that the tree with `current` as root has